# Max number of Illustrious Jewelcrafter's Tokens in a day

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is it currently only possible to receive 1x Illustrious Jewelcrafter's Token per day? Are there any other quests outside of the trainer in Orgrimmar where I can get more dailies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is only possible to get one per day, from the daily quest each day.

http://www.wowhead.com/currency=361/illustrious-jewelcrafters-token#reward-from-q confirms this as well.

Answer (score 0):

It will take you 281 days (if you don't miss any) to get all of the tokens required for the cuts.